# Service principal to DECRYPT 'Always Encrypted Azure SQL DB' using certificate instead of client secret

Tags: certificate, odbc, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I have a Azure SQL DB with always encrypted feature enabled using Azure Key Vault Key.

I want to consume this from a Power BI report. So I'm using a Data Gateway in the middle, with ODBC connection and a Service principal (Client/Secret) who is able to access the Key (from Azure Key Vault). Everything is working fine but for security constraints I need to change this Service principal Authentication to Certificate.

[Imagen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHdaU.png)

[Imagen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tn8k.png)

I want to know if it is possible to change this authentication (that allows ODBC connection to get the Azure Key vault and Decrypt data) to Azure service principal with a certificate (and not a client secret).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, For now there’s no option in ODBC Driver Administrator to add app certificate for column encryption.

I tried to add the SQL Server connection like below:-

[image]

There’s no option to add the certificate or certificate based app authentication in the key store authentication:-

[image]

[image]

In SSMS also there’s no option to add client certificate in the column encryption, Refer below:-

[image]

While connecting to Azure SQL Data source with Power BI, there’s no direct authentication available for app certificate, refer below:-

[image]

[image]

But you can connect your Azure service principal to Power BI by allowing Power BI to access service principal:-

**Add your Service principal with certificate in one Azure AD group and then allow that group here:-**

Created an Azure AD group and added my Service Principal:-

[image]

[image]

Power BI:-

***Visit [app.powerbi.com](http://app.powerbi.com) > Log ion to your Power BI workspace > Settings on the right > Admin Portal > Tenant Settings > Developer Settings > allow Service principal to use Power BI API’s > ENABLE and add ypur security group that contains your service principal***

[image]

***Share your dataset directly with the Service Principal or by giving the permissions to the Service Principal:-***

[image]

[image]

Also, SQL server authentication with certificate is only available for Azure ARC based servers.

***References:-***

[Set up Azure Active Directory authentication for SQL Server - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/azure-ad-authentication-sql-server-setup-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver16)

[Tutorial: Getting started with Always Encrypted - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-tutorial-getting-started?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms)

[Tutorial: Getting started with Always Encrypted - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-tutorial-getting-started?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms)

[Embed Power BI content in an embedded analytics application with service principal and an application secret - Power BI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal)